# Issue with microsoft websites browsing

Tags: windows-7, opera

From quite a few days i am unable to access microsoft communities websites and MSDN documentations etc.Is anyone suffering the same?
Example. I am unable to see the proper formatted page like [microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)...
All contents are poorly formatted.

Is this a potential issue or an individual issue?Why is this?

Platform:Win7, Browser:Opera

Comment: Will u help me post a screen having low score of reputation points at this stage? @Dave

Comment: So, first question, does the same issue persist using IE or Firefox or Chrome

Comment: Oh it started work right now.......but again its capricious.might be next time it can worry me.besides slow internet connection what are the other major reasons?

Comment: Bad internet connection, fault rendering the content, a plugin issue, MS making updates, your Internet Security software... the list goes. Next time it goes wrong, try a different browser and see if the same issue persists. If it does then you know the fault is unlikely a browser, but could be a plugin, Internet Security or their end... The only way to know the issue is trial and error

Comment: Well,i am having the same page distorted-layout of a site on both chrome and opera.Seems an issue from that end

Comment: You should EDIT your original question with this new information as it will mean other people reading this will see it. Remember, this is a Q&A site, not a forum so it's fine to edit in this manner :)

Comment: And your edit didn't really work - you say you can't access the site, the say it renders incorrectly...

Comment: This reminds me of when MSN deliberately served bad stylesheets to Opera users (at least when they didn't change their user agent string) to make Opera look like it couldn't display the site properly. Opera raised a stink about it (and rightly so) and, in response, released the [Opera "bork" edition](http://slashdot.org/story/03/02/14/1256231/opera-releases-bork-edition) both as a joke and to make a point. It was absolutely hilarious to read MSN with everything sounding like it was said by the Swedish chef from the Muppets :-D

Comment: Haha maybe the arch rivalry still continues :) @AmosM.Carpenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments, the issue continues in different browsers (Opera and Chrome) and unless you're sharing a single plugin through out it's unlikely the fault is with the browser itself.

However, the reason **why** is still broad, especially as it is intermittent.

It could be your Internet Security (if using) - it could, for example, be detecting some images as banners and trying to block them which could have this layout issue.

It could be the site you're trying to view is currently updating or there is a fault.

It could be the connection between yourself and the host is not stable and during some requests, only some of the information is transmitted to the browser. You can test this by pinging the destination IP continuously for a minute and check how many packets are lost.

Comment: Well,it's a long list to keep testing/checking...I would stay cool with this problem instead of testing it now but definitely would look into it later

Answer (score 0):

Some websites think that, if you are running Opera, you must be using a mobile phone or tablet, and they give a display suited for that device. Unfortunately it is not consistent. It happens to my wife when she goes to cua.com.au (it actually loads m.cua.com.au) but for me cua is fine. I have also seen it with Portable Opera on some PC/website combinations, while others are fine.

Try removing Opera's ini file. The name and location depend on the Opera version you are using. For Opera 12 it's operaprefs.ini. For current versions, remove the Profile and Cache folders